# Shiny app can't read in file name stored in variable

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, dygraphs, shinydashboard

I have a problem with the data visualization respectively processing a csv file in a Shiny application. I get this error message: "*Error: 'file' must be a character string or connection*." The chart is therefore not shown because the data seemingly can not be read in. It should be noted that the file name is stored in a variable. Oddly, but everything works fine in the console.

Below I have added the appropriate code of server.R and an exemplary folder.

The rough and planned operation of the app displayed in the code:
The user can set two reactive input options first the unit of time and, second, the respective desired fruit.
In the first step ie all *daily* csv files are getting loaded. In the second step, all files with the word *Apples* are loaded. So, now we have only daily data of the apples. Next we only want the data for the first chart and here it hooks.

I have now tried for hours just nearly everything and not get ahead.I have also tried to test other formats like RDS instead of csv files. Then came an error message a la "Bad file".

I hope someone can help. Thanks in advance.

```
# server.R
server <- function(input, output, session) {

# input form one
getAll <- reactive({
  switch(input$all,
    "Daily" = dir(path = "folder/all", pattern = "daily", 
      full.names = TRUE),
    "Weekly" = dir(path = "folder/all", pattern = "weekly", 
      full.names = TRUE),
    "Monthly" = dir(path = "folder/all", pattern = "monthly", 
      full.names = TRUE))
})


# input form two
getSome <- reactive({
  switch(input$some,
    "Apples" = getAll[c(grep(getAll, pattern = "Apples"), value = FALSE)]),
    "Bananas" = getAll[c(grep(getAll, pattern = "Bananas"), value = FALSE)],
    "Cherries" = getAll[c(grep(getAll, pattern = "Cherries"), value = FALSE)],
    "Kiwis" = getAll[c(grep(getAll, pattern = "Kiwis"), value = FALSE)],
    "Strawberries" = getAll[c(grep(getAll, pattern = "Strawberries"), value = FALSE)])
})


# Apples Chart 1

dygraph_Apples_Input <- function() {

  getApples_Only <- getSome()

  getApples_Only_Chart1 <- getApples_Only[c(grep(
    getApples_Only, pattern = "Chart1"), value = FALSE)]

  getApples_Only_Data <- read.csv(
    file = getApples_Only_Chart1[1],
    sep = ";",
    header = TRUE,
    encoding = "UTF-8")

    ...

}

output$dygraph_Apples_Chart1 <- renderDygraph({
  dygraph_Apples_Input()
})
```

[image]

Folder content:

- daily_Apples_Chart1.csv
- daily_Apples_Chart2.csv
- daily_Apples_Chart3.csv
- daily_Apples_Chart4.csv
- daily_Apples_Chart5.csv
- daily_Bananas_Chart1.csv
- daily_Bananas_Chart2.csv
- daily_Bananas_Chart3.csv
- daily_Bananas_Chart4.csv
- daily_Bananas_Chart5.csv
- daily_Cherries_Chart1.csv
- daily_Cherries_Chart2.csv
- daily_Cherries_Chart3.csv
- daily_Cherries_Chart4.csv
- daily_Cherries_Chart5.csv
- daily_Kiwis_Chart1.csv
- daily_Kiwis_Chart2.csv
- daily_Kiwis_Chart3.csv
- daily_Kiwis_Chart4.csv
- daily_Kiwis_Chart5.csv
- daily_Strawberries_Chart1.csv
- daily_Strawberries_Chart2.csv
- daily_Strawberries_Chart3.csv
- daily_Strawberries_Chart4.csv
- daily_Strawberries_Chart5.csv
- weekly_Apples_Chart1.csv
- weekly_Apples_Chart2.csv
- weekly_Apples_Chart3.csv
- weekly_Apples_Chart4.csv
- weekly_Apples_Chart5.csv
- weekly_Bananas_Chart1.csv
- weekly_Bananas_Chart2.csv
- weekly_Bananas_Chart3.csv
- weekly_Bananas_Chart4.csv
- weekly_Bananas_Chart5.csv
- weekly_Cherries_Chart1.csv
- weekly_Cherries_Chart2.csv
- weekly_Cherries_Chart3.csv
- weekly_Cherries_Chart4.csv
- weekly_Cherries_Chart5.csv
- weekly_Kiwis_Chart1.csv
- weekly_Kiwis_Chart2.csv
- weekly_Kiwis_Chart3.csv
- weekly_Kiwis_Chart4.csv
- weekly_Kiwis_Chart5.csv
- weekly_Strawberries_Chart1.csv
- weekly_Strawberries_Chart2.csv
- weekly_Strawberries_Chart3.csv
- weekly_Strawberries_Chart4.csv
- weekly_Strawberries_Chart5.csv
- ...

Comment: So what is the value you get from `getApples_Only_Chart1[1]`?

Comment: In the console I get the right value "daily_Apples_Chart1.csv" und reading, visualizing the data works. Running the app the console output looks like this: `Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3318
Warnung: Error in read.table: 'file' must be a character string or connection
Stack trace (innermost first):
    71: read.table
    70: read.csv
    69: dygraph_Apples_Input [/Users/mhn/Desktop/thefruitsapp/server.R#120]
    68: func [/Users/mhn/Desktop/thefruitsapp/server.R#160]
    67: output$dygraph_Apples_Chart1
     1: runApp`

Comment: Try one of the debugging methods here http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/debugging.html and see what is the value of `getApples_Only_Chart1[1]` when you run the app.

Comment: I checked the `showReactLog()` function and saw that there was something wrong in my ui.R and fixed it. Now the error has changed. There seems to be something wrong with my second reactive expression. The console output now says: `Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7362
Warnung: Error in as.vector: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
Stack trace (innermost first):
    85: as.character.default
    84: as.character
    83: structure
    82: grep
    81: reactive getSome [/Users/mhn/Desktop/thefruitsapp/server.R#44]
    70: getSome`

Comment: I just noticed that this line has two `getAll` which is apparently an error. `    "Apples" = getAll(getAll[c(grep(getAll, pattern = "Apples"), value = FALSE)]),`

Comment: @warmoverflow sorry this was just a copy&paste error. The error remains: `Error in as.vector: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105464/discussion-between-warmoverflow-and-mhn).

Comment: I think in `"Apples" = getAll[c(grep(getAll, pattern = "Apples"), value = FALSE)]),`, it probably should be `getAll()[...]`? (And you have an extra `)` at the end of the line.

Comment: Awesome, you are right! Adding four parentheses and it works.  getAll()[c(grep(getAll(), ...)] did the job.